# Unable to resolve 189.0: missing requirement [189.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=bsh)

Tags: jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

Just another one from "Jira plugin development dependency hell" series.

```
> Unable to resolve 189.0: missing requirement [189.0]
> osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=bsh).  This error usually
> occurs when your plugin imports a package from another bundle with a
> specific version constraint and either the bundle providing that
> package doesn't meet those version constraints, or there is no bundle
> available that provides the specified package. For more details on how
> to fix this, see https://developer.atlassian.com/x/mQAN
```

Basically, I followed instructions found here: [Tutorial - Writing JIRA event listeners with the atlassian-event library](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/guides/other/tutorial-writing-jira-event-listeners-with-the-atlassian-event-library)

Tried removing slf4j dependency, and I got a bit different error. Also, I've noticed that number 189.0 is not consistent over redeploys.

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

I got this a few times already too, but with bitbucket development most of these errors could be resolved by checking pom - dependency (check version too since they use a lot of older versions), check your atlassian-plugin.xml + osgi reference if you do not use the altassian spring scanner.

I hope this is helping somehow, good luck!